# Objective-C – ASIHTTPRequest caches even if new content is available

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I'm using `ASIHTTPRequest` to download data from the internet. It has a nifty cacheing feature that you can turn on so that it caches the downloaded data. So far so good. But when I upload new data to my webserver and try to download it again I'm expecting it **not** to use the cache since the data is new and modified. But even so it will **still use** the cache.

I'm using the following code for my request:

```
[ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];

// When you turn shouldRespectCacheControlHeaders off, the cache will store responses even if the server 
// has explictly asked for them not be be cached (eg with a cache-control or pragma: no-cache header)
[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] setShouldRespectCacheControlHeaders:NO];

NSURL *officesUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/example.json"];
ASIHTTPRequest *officesRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:officesUrl];

[officesRequest setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[officesRequest addRequestHeader:@"Cache-Control" value:@"no-cache"];

// Always ask the server if there is new content available, 
// If the request fails, use data from the cache even if it should have expired.
[officesRequest setCachePolicy:ASIAskServerIfModifiedCachePolicy|ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy];

[officesRequest setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];

[officesRequest setDelegate:self];

[officesRequest startAsynchronous];
```

**EDIT:**

Two images to show the different headers from HTTPScoop. First image is a fresh download with no cached content. Second image I have uploaded new and modified data.

First:

[image]

Second:

[image]

**EDIT2**: Added logs

https://gist.github.com/1139351

Comment: Perhaps ASIHTTPRequest makes use of the ETag to figure out if content has changed and your server doesn't change the ETag on change of content? See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

Comment: Collect a http trace for the initial fetch (with an empty cache) and another trace for the request that incorrectly caches using a tool like charlesproxy, then edit the data into your question.

Comment: By any chance, are you running in the simulator?  I think the simulator itself may employ a cache.  I ran into an issue where running in the simulator, even though I was explicitly setting the cache policy on my ASIHTTPRequest to (ASIDoNotReadFromCacheCachePolicy | ASIDoNotWriteToCacheCachePolicy), it was returning an old result.  This behavior didn't happen on device, though.

Comment: @JosephH: I've updated with images now, open them up in new tabs to see full size.

Comment: @Joe Ibanez: This occurs on the device as well :(

Comment: It appears there the server is returning new content. What do you see if you enable all the asihttprequest logging?

Comment: @JosephH Should I set `DEBUG_REQUEST_STATUS 0` to 1 ? Or any other logging?

Comment: I just tend to set all the DEBUG_ entries to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was expecting way more debug output than that, I'm not sure why you got so little.

I think you are just going to have to step through the response processing and see why it decides the cached version is okay to use. The code's pretty easy to follow.

Try setting a breakpoint on `useDataFromCache` in ASIHTTPRequest.m to start with and `canUseCachedDataForRequest`, particularly when called from `readResponseHeaders`.

Comment: Don't really know what I should be looking for in the debugging? Can you give me a URL that ASIHTTPRequest is caching properly?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on useDataFromCache - whoever is calling that is doing so erroneously in your case, so when the breakpoint gets hit go up a level and see what condition is being satisfied and resulting in useDataFromCache being called.